# how to open new activity from a thread with an handler

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler

at the beginning every thing worked well, but i changed things and now the applcation crash when i open the new activity from a thread (not the UI thread).

the application only crash on my phone after installation, in debug mode it work well for some reason i can't understand.

this is my handler:

```
handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

// --- thread work function ---
public void OnLoseActivity()
{
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent myActivity= new Intent(mainActivity.this, newActivity.class);
            startActivity(myActivity);
        }
    });
}
```

something that i am doing wrong?

need to handle other issues before closing this first activity?

thanks

**Update:**

the reason i open an activity from a thread is that the thread checking for something in a loop, if it happand the activity shuold open.

I am not used to work with handlers, explain to me if im doing newb things please.

as i wrote, nothing special in the logcat because on debug it's working fine

Comment: Why are you using a handler with a runnable to start the new Activity?

Comment: you don't need the `Looper.getMainLooper()` bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running this in an Activity, try this. Put your Intent in a method and call the method in your Runnable.

```
void startMyActivity()
{
            Intent myActivity= new Intent(mainActivity.this, newActivity.class);
            startActivity(myActivity);
}
```

and change your Runnable:

```
 new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startMyActivity();
        }
    });
```